# Type Mismatch error parsing JSON with Swift Decodable

Tags: json, swift, decodable

When I try to decode JSON I get the error:

> (Error:  typeMismatch(Swift.String, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [sweetyanime.Video.(CodingKeys in _D1045E05CDE474AEBA8BDCAF57455DC3).video, sweetyanime.iD.(CodingKeys in _D1045E05CDE474AEBA8BDCAF57455DC3).ID, sweetyanime.other.(CodingKeys in _D1045E05CDE474AEBA8BDCAF57455DC3).CountOfVideos], debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)

1) JSON:

```
{ "video":{  

  "ID":{ 

     "Name":"NameOfAnime",
     "Describe":"SomeDescribe",
     "Image":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweety-anime-e6bb4.appspot.com/o/main.png?alt=media&token=042a2dad-8519-4904-9ba3-262c2c962434",
     "CountOfVideos":{  
        "1Series":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sweety-anime-e6bb4.appspot.com/o/message_movies%252F12323439-9729-4941-BA07-2BAE970967C7.movalt=media&token=978d8b3a-7aad-468f-87d4-2b587d616720"
     }
  } } }
```

2) Swift code:

```
let jsonUrl = "file:///Users/tima/WebstormProjects/untitled/db.json"
guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrl) else { return }

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, reponse, error) in
    guard let data = data else {return}
    do {
        let video = try
            JSONDecoder().decode(Video.self, from: data)
        print(video.video.ID.Name)
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print("Error: ", jsonErr)
    }
}.resume()
```

3) Video.swift

```
struct Video: Decodable {
   private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case video = "video" 
   }
   let video: iD
}

struct iD: Decodable {
   private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case ID = "ID" }
   let ID: other
}

struct other: Decodable {
   private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
      case Name = "Name"
      case Describe = "Describe"
      case Image = "Image"
      case CountOfVideos = "CountOfVideos"
   }
   let Name: String
   let Describe: String
   let Image: String
   let CountOfVideos: String
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's put some line breaks in your error message to make it understandable:

```
(Error: typeMismatch(Swift.String,
    Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [
        sweetyanime.Video.(CodingKeys in _D1045E05CDE474AEBA8BDCAF57455DC3).video,
        sweetyanime.iD.(CodingKeys in _D1045E05CDE474AEBA8BDCAF57455DC3).ID,
        sweetyanime.other.(CodingKeys in _D1045E05CDE474AEBA8BDCAF57455DC3).CountOfVideos],
    debugDescription: "Expected to decode String but found a dictionary instead.",
    underlyingError: nil)
```

So it was trying to decode the value for “CountOfVideos”. It expected a String but it found a dictionary.

You need to either define a `struct` corresponding to the “CountOfVideos” dictionary (it appears to contain one key, “1Series”, with a string value), or you need to remove the `CountOfVideos` property from your `other` struct so you don't try to decode it at all.

Answer (score -1):

My I think you should implement the init(from decoder) initializer that is part of Decodable. It gives a lot more flexibility on how to handle nested JSON than you get from the automatic implementation. One possible implementation would be something like:

```
struct Video: Decodable {
let name: String
let describe: String
let image: String
let countOfVideos: String

private enum VideoKey: String, CodingKey {
    case video = "video"
}

private enum IDKey: String, CodingKey {
    case id = "ID"
}

private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "Name"
    case describe = "Describe"
    case image = "Image"
    case countOfVideos = "CountOfVideos"
}

private enum VideoCountKey: String, CodingKey {
    case videoCount = "1Series"
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let videoContainer = try decoder.container(keyedBy: VideoKey.self)
    let idContainer = try videoContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: IDKey.self, forKey: .video)
    let valuesContainer = try idContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self, forKey: .id)
    self.name = try valuesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    self.describe = try valuesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .describe)
    self.image = try valuesContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .image)
    let videoCountContainer = try valuesContainer.nestedContainer(keyedBy: VideoCountKey.self, forKey: .countOfVideos)
    self.countOfVideos = try videoCountContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .videoCount)
}
```

This works with your example data in a Playground. I really don't know if you wanted the key or the value for your videoCount. (Neither looks like a count of videos to me.  Generally, you just need to define a CodingKey enum for every level of your nested JSON and you can decode individual values as you see fit. (Note, since I've only seen one example of your data, this may break on some stuff in whatever API you're working with, so modify/take the ideas and rewrite it as needed)